# Windows 2008 User CALs on Windows 2012 Server

Tags: windows, licensing, cals

We are about to upgrade our Domain Controller from Server2008 to Server2012. We have User CALs that we currently use for our Server2008 DC. When we upgrade to Server 2012 can we continue to use those 2008 CALs?

I've found contradictory answers so far, some say yes some say no. The official Microsoft site seems to say yes - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14988.rds-and-ts-cal-interoperability-matrix.aspx

Do I need to purchase those extra licenses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need new CAL if your users will authenticate against that server.

TS-CAL/RDS-CAL can be downgrade in some case, like if you have a 2008R2 TS and 2012 RDS-CAL, the system will use those CAL if they can't find a 2008R2 TS CAL. (and the article you site is about RDS aka TS CAL too, not normal user CAL)